# how to keep data from a webpage, if the webpage sits on usb stick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm tryin to make a small html quiz, that can be started with a browser from an usb stick on any plattform.

The quiz is really simple. The user opens the webpage and see's the first question. He can click on answer A,B,C or D. After the user has clicked on A,B,C or D, he get's the right answer and a message if he was right or wrong. Then he is asked the next question. and so on.

At the end, he get's a page which displays how many questions were answered right. That's all about the quiz.

At the moment the problem is, how can i keep the point's the users has get from one page to another?
Should I use cookies? Or is there a better way of storing the "points"?

Comment: Why don't you host your html quiz in a server and store user result in file or database?

Comment: Because, it has to work from a usb stick. :)

Comment: IF it will help me to find a solution, yes. :)

Answer (score 1):

I created quiz like that one day. In my case the point was to use JSON to store questions (json has been loaded from local file via ajax), with answers, so i was able to randomly choose questions for user and then save number of correct answers/mistakes in js variables.

```
<div id="question">Load question there</div>
<ul>
    <li id="answer-1">load first answer</li>
    <li>and so on...</li>
</ul>
```

Loading json from file is easy using [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$.getJSON('./questions.json', function(json) {
    // save json somewhere for futher use.
});
```

After quiz ends i use ajax to load page with quiz summary, where i have prepared 'anchors' to insert number of correct answers dynamically. Everything without any page reload.

But you have to remember, that Chrome Browser does not accept file:// protocol to ajax, so this method will not work in Chrome. Aiddotional information about this issue can be found [there](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/give-feature-feedback-and-suggestions/v177zA6LCKU).

Comment: Yes. And i suggest you to use jQuery also to easier handle with this all operations.

Comment: Oh that sounds nice, could you give me some hints about how to read data from json files? Maybe do you have a link with some more informations?

Comment: Sure, i improved my answer. You can easly use jQuery.getJSON function

Answer (score 0):

You could check out HTML5 local storage:

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

This will allow you to store data on the local computer. The API is a bit more flexible then cookies, with the disadvantage that will only work on the latest browsers. If you want to support older versions as well you need a polyfill. The following list contains a polyfill for local storage: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Note: you will only be able to save data to the local computer, not to the USB stick. The browser will not allow you to save data to the USB stick directly, so data won't be portable to another PC.

Comment: The data should not be saved to the USB stick directly, It's just needed for the actual session of the Browser. It's okay if everything is deleted after closing the browser.

Comment: Oh, if it's only for the current session you can keep it in memory. Just save it in a JavaScript variable and you will be fine